# Importing a csv onto a second sheet

Tags: vba, excel

i need to import a csv file into excel using VBA. however i would like to import the data onto sheet 2 (A1) rather than sheet 1.

any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: record macro, see the code

Comment: @MarcinSzaleniec just beat me to the same comment. Had to double check you could record that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have two steps, First open a csv file, next copy and paste

First open a CSV File

```
Sub CopyCSVContent()

Workbooks.Open Filename:="YourPath\YourFileName.csv"

Application.Run "NExtStep"

End Sub
```

Second Copy every columns in your CSV and close csv

```
Sub NExtStep()

WorkBooks("YourFile.CSV").Worksheets(1).Columns("A:YOURLASTCOLUM").Copy

Workbooks("ImportFile.XLSM").WorkSheets(2).Range("A1").Paste

WorkBooks("YourFile.CSV").Close

End Sub
```